# SQL UPDATE Capital letters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day

I have problem with my script

```
UPDATE [dbo].[table]
SET
       [columnX] = replace([columnX], 'A', 'Ľ')

UPDATE [dbo].[table]
SET
       [columnX] = replace([columnX], 'ľ ', 'B')

Select * from [dbo].[table]

columnX
BzzBzz
BzzzzBBz
BzzzzzBB
BzzzBB
```

I need result like this:

```
columnX
BzzĽzz
ĽzzzzBBz
BzzzzzĽB
BzzzBĽ
```

What can I change to make my Update correct /give him know about LOWER and UPPER LETTERS
I CAN NOT CHANGE ORDER because I need to make so much updates and change of order make other conflicts..
Thanks guys

Comment: If you are replacing all `A`s with `L`s then there won't be any `A` in the output. Could you post the exising data and expected result?

Comment: Do you mean replacing `A` with `Ľ` does not get any match?

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different, unrelated software packages produced by different companies. Please use the correct tags. The code you posted is for [tag:sql-server].

Comment: whats the original data look like?

Answer (score 1):

Use case-sensetive collation (example for `Latin1_General`, but you should use your own collation):

```
UPDATE [dbo].[table]
SET [columnX] = replace([columnX], 'A' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'Ľ')
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple method is to start with

```
UPDATE [dbo].[table]
SET
       [columnX] = replace([columnX], 'ľ ', 'B')
```

Then

```
UPDATE [dbo].[table]
SET
       [columnX] = replace([columnX], 'A', 'Ľ')
```

Answer (score -1):

update table set columnX = 'AzzzzBAz' where columnX ='AzzzzAAz'

update table set columnX = 'AzzzAB' where columnX ='AzzzAA'

Comment: would you explain more clarity , what you want  to update for example columnx have BzzBzz  and it want to change to after two z  is there any scenario